# How to use .replace(/\+/g, ' ') method dynamically

Tags: javascript

I'm able to use  `.replace(/\+/g, ' ');`  jQuery method.

But I need to use it with dynamic parameters.

*Example:*

```
var str1 = 'aaa';
$('#myelement').val().replace(/str1\/g,' ');
```

How can I do that ?

Comment: it's not a jQuery method but an JS native string method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with `string.replace()` is Javascript and not jQuery. for more info check out [String.replace on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Also `string.replace()` returns a new string with the replacements and does not affect the string it's run against.

You can create a new RegExp with any arbitrary pattern

```
var regex = new RegExp('aaa', 'g');
```

then do:

```
var replacedString = $('#myelement').val().replace(regex,' ');
```

to get the string with the substitutions.

So to replace the content you'll have to do:

```
$('#myelement').val($('#myelement').val().replace(regex,' '));
```

Answer (score 1):

First of `$('#myelement')` will give you a jQuery object, you must replace the string inside its html or value. Try this:

```
var str1 = 'aaa';
var reg = new RegExp(str1,"g");
$('#myelement').val($('#myelement').val().replace(reg, ' '));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#myelement').val($('#myelement').val().replace(/str1\/g,' '));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 var pattern = /(aaa)\b/g;
 $('#myelement').val().replace(pattern,' ');
```